# SQL Server 2008 mirroring on AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

Building a application on Amazon Web Services (AWS) using SQL Server 2008 and don't have the budget for Enterprise Edition.  It's a standard web app, nothing too fancy needed in the way of performance.

I've proposed Synchronous Database Mirroring, with the principal server being in one availability zone (AZ) and the mirror located in a second AZ.  My colleagues (DBA & Data architect) are shooting down this proposal, saying they never like to use synchronous mirroring as it can add latency and slow performance (like a two-phase commit).  They are willing to deal with the tradeoffs of log shipping to avoid this potential performance hit.

Any thoughts on this?  Are the performance risks of synchronous mirroring really that bad?

Comment: Potentially, especially on Amazon where EBS can cause major, unpredictable slowdowns.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts are you should thoroughly explore the pros and cons with your (obviously qualified) colleagues, conduct a risk/cost/benefit analysis, and make a decision appropriate to ***your*** environment.

In general though, your colleagues are correct: Synchronous mirroring can be a performance killer, particularly when you're talking about replication over a network which is not high-throughput and ultra-reliable.
In a case like yours "In *The Cloud*", where you have no performance guarantees and the potential for LOTS of variability), I would avoid synchronous replication strategies.